# JSON reading from assets folder not displaying

Tags: android, json, listview

i am building a listview to display from a JSON i got in my assets folder
for some reason i dont get anything displayed in the listview and it is empty, i am using the same code i used for a online JSON code i made a while ago with a few edits, the activity loads fine but nothing is seen

my codes

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dua);

    BuildDrawer();
    RightBuildDrawer();

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();  

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dua_listview);

    new GetContacts().execute();

}




public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("dua.json");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}   


private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DuaActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {




            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());

                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Duas");

                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("_id");
                    String category = c.getString("category");
                    String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                    String arabic = c.getString("arabic");
                    String translation = c.getString(TAG_TRANSLATION);
                    String transliteration = c.getString(TAG_TRANSLITERATION);
                    String reference = c.getString(TAG_REFERENCE);                                            

                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_CATEGORY, category);
                    contact.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                    contact.put(TAG_ARABIC, arabic);
                    contact.put(TAG_TRANSLATION, translation);
                    contact.put(TAG_TRANSLITERATION, transliteration);
                    contact.put(TAG_REFERENCE, reference);  

                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */

        adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(
                DuaActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.dua_list_item, new String[] { TAG_CATEGORY, TAG_TITLE}, 
                        new int[] { R.id.duaName,R.id.duaCategory});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter2);      
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // ENTER HERE

            }
        });
    }

}
```

this is my JSON

```
{
  "Duas" : [
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "category" : "Sleep",
        "title" : "When waking up",
        "arabic" : "الْحَمْدُ للهِ الَّذِي أَحْيَانَا بَعْدَ مَا أَمَاتَنَا وَإِلَيْهِ النُّشُورُ",
        "translation" : "Praise is to Allah Who gives us life after He has caused us to die and to Him is the return.",
        "transliteration" : "Alhamdu lillaahil-lathee 'ahyaanaa ba'da maa 'amaatanaa wa'ilayhin-nushoor",
        "reference" : "Al-Bukhari, cf. Al-Asqalani, Fathul-Bari 11\/113; Muslim 4\/2083"
    },
  ]
}
```

logcat ::

```
07-03 02:45:52.531: W/System.err(14092): org.json.JSONException: Expected ':' after ?? at character 4 of {??
??
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092): ?? ?? ??"??D??u??a??s??"?? ??:?? ??[??
??
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092): ?? ?? ?? ?? ??{??
??
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092): ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??"??_??i??d??"?? ??:?? ??1??,??
??
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092): ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??"??c??a??t??e??g??o??r??y??"?? ??:?? ??"??S??l??e??e??p??"??,??
??
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092): ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??"??t??i??t??l??e??"?? ??:?? ??"??W??h??e??n?? ??w??a??k??i??n??g?? ??u??p??"??,??
??
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092): ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??"??a??r??a??b??i??c??"?? ??:?? ??"??'DR-NER/O ??DDGP ??'DNQ0PJ ??#N-RJN'FN' ??(N9R/N ??EN' ??#NEN'*NFN' ??HN%PDNJRGP ??'DFOQ4OH1O"??,??
??
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092): ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??"??t??r??a??n??s??l??a??t??i??o??n??"?? ??:?? ??"??P??r??a??i??s??e?? ??i??s?? ??t??o?? ??A??l??l??a??h?? ??W??h??o?? ??g??i??v??e??s?? ??u??s?? ??l??i??f??e?? ??a??f??t??e??r?? ??H??e?? ??h??a??s?? ??c??a??u??s??e??d?? ??u??s?? ??t??o?? ??d??i??e?? ??a??n??d?? ??t??o?? ??H??i??m?? ??i??s?? ??t??h??e?? ??r??e??t??u??r??n??.??"??,??
??
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092): ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??"??t??r??a??n??s??l??i??t??e??r??a??t??i??o??n??"?? ??:?? ??"??A??l??h??a??m??d??u?? ??l??i??l??l??a??a??h??i??l??-??l??a??t??h??e??e?? ??'??a??h??y??a??a??n??a??a?? ??b??a??'??d??a?? ??m??a??a?? ??'??a??m??a??a??t??a??n??a??a?? ??w??a??'??i??l??a??y??h??i??n??-??n??u??s??h??o??o??r??"??,??
??
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092): ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??"??r??e??f??e??r??e??n??c??e??"?? ??:?? ??"??A??l??-??B??u??k??h??a??r??i??,?? ??c??f??.?? ??A??l??-??A??s??q??a??l??a??n??i??,?? ??F??a??t??h??u??l??-??B??a??r??i?? ??1??1??\??/??1??1??3??;?? ??M??u??s??l??i??m?? ??4??\??/??2??0??8??3??"??
??
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092): ?? ?? ?? ?? ??}??
??
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092): ?? ?? ??]??
??
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092): ??}??
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092):    at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:379)
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092):    at com.sahaab.muslimzone.activity.DuaActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(DuaActivity.java:172)
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092):    at com.sahaab.muslimzone.activity.DuaActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(DuaActivity.java:1)
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-03 02:45:52.541: W/System.err(14092):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON has a comma in the wrong place:

```
{
    "Duas": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "category": "Sleep",
            "title": "When waking up",
            "arabic": "الْحَمْدُ للهِ الَّذِي أَحْيَانَا بَعْدَ مَا أَمَاتَنَا وَإِلَيْهِ النُّشُورُ",
            "translation": "Praise is to Allah Who gives us life after He has caused us to die and to Him is the return.",
            "transliteration": "Alhamdu lillaahil-lathee 'ahyaanaa ba'da maa 'amaatanaa wa'ilayhin-nushoor",
            "reference": "Al-Bukhari, cf. Al-Asqalani, Fathul-Bari 11/113; Muslim 4/2083"
        }, <----- this should not be here
    ]
}
```

This is the correct JSON.

```
{
    "Duas": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "category": "Sleep",
            "title": "When waking up",
            "arabic": "الْحَمْدُ للهِ الَّذِي أَحْيَانَا بَعْدَ مَا أَمَاتَنَا وَإِلَيْهِ النُّشُورُ",
            "translation": "Praise is to Allah Who gives us life after He has caused us to die and to Him is the return.",
            "transliteration": "Alhamdu lillaahil-lathee 'ahyaanaa ba'da maa 'amaatanaa wa'ilayhin-nushoor",
            "reference": "Al-Bukhari, cf. Al-Asqalani, Fathul-Bari 11/113; Muslim 4/2083"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: json fromat is right they just show us json look like above.

Comment: @ArunKumar It worked on http://json.parser.online.fr/. You just removed the coma, which is needed in an array. IMO the json is correct if the coma is removed.

Comment: OMG i saw first time in my life

Comment: @Golu The JSON was invalid, so this is a valid answer. Altough it was missing the reason why it was incorrect...

Comment: Correct answer only description  is missing.

Comment: Can u provide full code then i can approach to help?

Comment: If there is an issue to copy here then u can mail on kumararun2008@gmail.com. After the correction i will reply to u and will add here.

Comment: you can download from here the related files
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h99hhrpdz51wa2k/DuaActivity.rar

Comment: the whole JSON is pretty big, i was just using with 1 array to test it with, first i tried whole JSON but didnt work

Comment: i finally noticed a logcat, adding to OP

Comment: @Sahaab Can u tell me what exactly listview will show?

Comment: it is going to show the Category and the Title @Arun

Comment: well i tried many differnent JSONs now and have found out that its not the JSONs fault

Answer (score 1):

I think you code is throwing a JSONException (Which you are swallowing and probably have missed).

The JSON is incorrect due the last comma:

```
{
  "Duas" : [
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "category" : "Sleep",
        "title" : "When waking up",
        "arabic" : "الْحَمْدُ للهِ الَّذِي أَحْيَانَا بَعْدَ مَا أَمَاتَنَا وَإِلَيْهِ النُّشُورُ",
        "translation" : "Praise is to Allah Who gives us life after He has caused us to die and to Him is the return.",
        "transliteration" : "Alhamdu lillaahil-lathee 'ahyaanaa ba'da maa 'amaatanaa wa'ilayhin-nushoor",
        "reference" : "Al-Bukhari, cf. Al-Asqalani, Fathul-Bari 11\/113; Muslim 4\/2083"
    }, <-- Remove this
  ]
}
```

Comment: well i tried that, sorry i think my eclipse is messing up, i dont think it added the update and etc

Comment: Well remove the '} catch (JSONException e) {' and see if it's showing an error. Don't catch exceptions if your not going to handle them. (and printing a stacktrace and continueing is not handling ;))

Comment: im sorry pretty new to android app development and dont know much bout catching errors and what to do after em :-/